# Testing Ipad Touch Events in Windows

Tags: ipad, html

I have a website that I would like to be iPad compatible. However, I use Windows, so I can't install the official emulator.

I tried iBBDemo2 (http://code.google.com/p/ibbdemo2/) which looks good, but it uses regular mouse events instead of the touch events (so I can double click with my mouse and fire a dblclick event on an element... which in this case would just cause a zoom to occur on a real iPad)

Is there any way at all to test this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried Ripple emulator? It is a very useful chrome extension. It has accelerometer support and other features.

The link is [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc).

I don't know if really solves your problem, but you can try it for free.